# empty() not a valid callback?

Tags: php, callback, array-map

I'm trying to use empty() in array mapping in php. I'm getting errors that it's not a valid callback.

```
$ cat test.php
<?

$arrays = array(
   'arrEmpty' => array(
        '','',''
    ),
);

foreach ( $arrays as $key => $array ) {

        echo $key . "\n";
        echo array_reduce( $array, "empty" );
        var_dump( array_map("empty", $array) );
        echo "\n\n";

}
```

---

```
$ php test.php
arrEmpty

Warning: array_reduce(): The second argument, 'empty', should be a valid callback in /var/www/authentication_class/test.php on line 12

Warning: array_map(): The first argument, 'empty', should be either NULL or a valid callback in /var/www/authentication_class/test.php on line 13
NULL
```

Shouldn't this work?

Long story: I'm trying to be (too?) clever and checking that all array values are not empty strings.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because `empty` is a language construct and not a function. From the [manual on empty():](http://www.php.net/empty)

> Note: Because this is a language construct and not a function, it cannot be called using variable functions

Comment: You know what I love about this site? That people aren't saying "RTFM!" :D

Comment: @user151841 we are not allowed to. That's the only reason ;)

Answer (score 7):

Try [`array_filter`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) with no callback instead:

> If no callback is supplied, all entries of input equal to FALSE  (see converting to boolean) will be removed.

You can then use `count(array_filter($array))` to see if it still has values.

Or simply wrap empty into a callable, like this:

```
array_reduce($array, create_function('$x', 'return empty($x);'));
```

or as of PHP 5.3

```
array_reduce($array, function($x) { return empty($x); });
```

Answer (score 2):

To add to the others, it's common for PHP developers to create a function like this:

```
function isEmpty($var)
{
    return empty($var);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Empty can't be used as a callback, it needs to operate on a variable. From the [manual](http://nl2.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

> Note: empty() only checks variables as anything else will result in a parse error. In other words, the following will not work: empty(trim($name)).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, somehow empty() worked for me inside a callback.

The reason why I was originally getting this error was because I was trying to callback as an independent function, whereas it was inside my class and I had to call it using array(&$this ,'func_name')

See code below. It works for me. I am php 5.2.8, if that matters...

```
$table_values = array_filter( $table_values, array(&$this, 'remove_blank_rows') );

function remove_blank_rows($row){


        $not_blank = false;

        foreach($row as $col){
            $cell_value = trim($col);
            if(!empty( $cell_value )) {
                $not_blank = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        return $not_blank;

}
```